# first time select takes time to execute in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

why does sql server take time during execution of query for the first time? I know it is because of the caching part and building of excution plans but what is the work around for this. I have a retail software and the first item scanned takes around 10 secs before it is added to the receipt and subsequent scans are fast.

Comment: Have you analysed the execution plan and ensured you have the correct indices, etc? Slow queries are often caused by missing indices.

Comment: it would also help to get an idea of your query, the amount of data you're selecting in.

Comment: Show the query and the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal. Try an EXPLAIN statement to see the execution plan. Most likely you are missing an index in a foreign key or you are doing an involved sort or something.

SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO allows you to see a graphical representation of the execution plan. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

and probably easier to look at : http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1856/sql-server-query-execution-plans-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Write the stored procedure having the select, even having the select inside the stored procedure still possess the same issue, but the cache will not be removed so easily as that of a ad-hoc query.